# Why the gridview in undefined when it's invisible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this gridview and I want to use the information from this gridview but I don't want to show it on the page.
So I set:  `grid.Visible = false`, but now the 'grid is not defined' error appear.
If `grid.Visible  = true`, everything work fine.
I have a javascript function who check this: `if (typeof (grid) !== "undefined")`, but my grid is not defined.
What is the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not rendered. With `grid.Visible` you control the rendering. Look at your HTML code. You will see, there is no code for the `GridView` if you set `grid.Visible = false`.

To hide it, use CSS instead: `display: none`:

```
grid.Style.Add("display", "none"); // not tested
```